# Emulate RFID Tag

Tags: rfid, emulation

I just got my RFID-RC522 Reader and was wondering one thing. Can i Use an RFID Reader to emulate an RFID Tag, so that if i have another reader it will detect the other one as a card and transfer data. It should be detected as a Tag like a midfare Classic but the data sould be supplied by the Arduino. Is this possible? At all? Or does it require another type of reader? If you know a solution please share it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive you cant use a RFID Reader to talk to another RFID Reader with the basic libraries and resources we have. You are best just getting an actual tag may it be Mifare classic or another type of RFID Tag.

I'm sure this is possible but the amount of development you will need to dedicate towards this would out weigh just getting a cheap RFID tag.

What you can do is look around see what type of things you have laying around maybe something has an RFID tag in it, or maybe you have a phone with NFC. You can use your phones NFC to send data to a RFID reader, but you will need to find the resources to do this. Sorry I'm not much help but maybe someone has done this before and has a simple solution.

Comment: This is not a very useful answer - first it is based on speculation rather than facts, and second your proposal "just getting an actual tag" ignores the question's goal that "the data should be supplied by the Arduino".